# How to disable translation tool in Nagios plugins?

Tags: nagios

Nagios plugins is using user setting to translate script response of check_http script. In my case, the server is in French and so the script return the response in French. Is it possible to disable the translation in Nagios ?

Comment: I would say that this setting is user browser specific.

Comment: Hi @Rohlik, The problem is not in the browser but in the script output :

`/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http -H 192.168.0.1  -u /status -p 8080 -w 1 -c 5`
`connect to address 192.168.0.1 and port 8080: Connexion refusée`
`HTTP CRITIQUE - Impossible d'ouvrir un socket TCP`

The output is in French because the script translate it based on user's language settings. As it is mentioned in nagios development guidelines  [link](http://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html). 
What I try to do is to disable this translation in nagios plugin if it is possible.